# Jquery insert class inside html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visual-composer

I have a set of tabs, when a class is active I want to add the following:

```
<hr class="break-sec">
```

This class has to be inside the span class and after the title-text class as shown below. Here is the code and where it has to be inserted.

```
<li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab="">
  <a href="#1485520583544" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
    <span class="vc_tta-title-text">
      GALLERY 
      <hr class="break-sec">
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

How can I accomplish this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `append` to `span/.vc_tta-title-text` based on the active li `vc_active` like :

```
$('.vc_active .vc_tta-title-text').append('<hr class="break-sec">');
//OR
$('.vc_active span').append('<hr class="break-sec">');
```

Add click event to make it append the `hr` dynamically :

```
$('body').on('click', '.vc_tta-tab', function(){
    $('.vc_tta-title-text hr').remove(); //remove 'hr' from previous active tab
    $('.vc_active span').append('<hr class="break-sec">'); //Add 'hr' to the new active tab
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.vc_active .vc_tta-title-text').append('<hr class="break-sec">');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
<a href="#1485520583544" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
  <span class="vc_tta-title-text">
    NOT ACTIVE
  </span>
</a>
</li>

<li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab="">
<a href="#1485520583544" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
  <span class="vc_tta-title-text">
    ACTIVE
  </span>
</a>
</li>

<li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
<a href="#1485520583544" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
  <span class="vc_tta-title-text">
    NOT ACTIVE
  </span>
</a>
</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: This half works, it adds the class to the current active tab however when another tab is clicked and it becomes active it does not apply the same rule...

Comment: Yes, since theres not handler on the change, which king of tabs lib are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are thinking about?

`$('.vc_tta-title-text').append('<hr class="break-sec">')` Will insert the `hr` right after the `Span` text

```js
$('.vc_active .vc_tta-title-text').append('<hr class="break-sec">')

$('.vc_tta-tab').click(function() {
$('.vc_active .vc_tta-title-text').find("hr").remove();
  $('.vc_active').removeClass("vc_active");
  $(this).addClass("vc_active");
  $('.vc_active .vc_tta-title-text').append('<hr class="break-sec">')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
  <a href="#1485520583544" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
    <span class="vc_tta-title-text">GALLERY 
</span></a>
</li>

<li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab="">
  <a href="#1485520583544" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
    <span class="vc_tta-title-text">PAGES 
</span></a>
</li>

<li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab="">
  <a href="#1485520583544" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta">
    <span class="vc_tta-title-text">VIDEOS 
</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: unfortunately this inserts it to all tabs and not just the active one.

Comment: whilst the following line of Jquery does add thge line break to the current active tab, when another tab is clicked and comes active it does not apply the HR class...$('.vc_active span').append('<hr class="break-sec-tabs">');

Comment: Updated, Is this what you want?

Comment: This half works yes and i can tween it :) Thank  you

Answer (score 0):

Mixed content is always a little more complicated, but [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) should do it:

```
$('span.vc_tta-title-text').append($('<hr class="break-sec">'));
```

(Putting the new content in a jQuery object converts it to DOM elements.)